# django default values for model forms

Tags: django, forms, model, default

I want a default (initial) value for a model form, with the least code as possible. I want to reuse it many times.
I don't want it to be default everytime when I save a model, like this does:

```
time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

I simply want it to be the default value in the form input.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just pass the initial dictionary to your model form's constructor like this:

```
MyForm(initial = {"name": "bla bla"})
```

Comment: How do I pass a date? Should I pass datetime or string?

Comment: I would pass it whatever the field type is in your models. If you have defined the field as datetime, then pass it a datetime object.